# Getting JsonException "Read too much or not enough" for my JsonConverter

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am receiving a property that could either have null `{ "some_obj" : null }` , an empty array [] `{ "some_obj" : [] }`, or an object has is not null with some properties `{ "some_obj" : 'name' : 'nick' }` as the value. In this context, an empty array should translate to null, so I created this converter.

```
public class MyConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T? Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
  
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, (T?)value, options);
}
```

When the data coming in is `{ "some_obj" : [] }`, the first if statement is true and I get the following the JsonException when returning `default(T)`: "The converter {converter} read too much or not enough." Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? When the data is `{ "some_obj" : null }` or `{ "some_obj" : 'name' : 'nick' }` , it's working fine.

I'm using the attribute on a type in one my classes

```
public class SomeClass
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter<SomeObj>))]
    [JsonPropertyName("some_obj")]
    public SomeObj? SomeObj{ get; set; }
}

public class SomeObj
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name{ get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Making sure I ended on JsonTokenType.EndArray was the solution. Thanks Simon for the ticket reference

```
public override T? Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
    }

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

        }
    }
    throw new JsonException();
}
```

Comment: Because you're exiting early from your converter, you're triggering a validation - it's expected that you read through the whole object.

Comment: Am I not exiting early as well in the else if block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `JsonConverter<T>.Read()`, if you want to ignore the contents of the current JSON token, you must advance the reader to end of the token, reading past any and all child tokens. The method [`Utf8JsonReader.Skip()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.skip?view=net-6.0) does this:

```
public class MyConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonTokenType.StartObject:
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
            default:
                {
                    reader.Skip();
                    return default(T);
                }               
        }
    }
```

This method *Skips the children of the current JSON token* which is necessary when the token to be ignored is an array (and does nothing in the event the current token is a primitive value such as `null`).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5UCuqP).

Notes:

- The version of the converter from your **UPDATE** will correctly skip past arrays without nested values such as `[]`, but will not correctly skip past arrays with nested child arrays such as `[[]]`.  In order to manually skip to the end of an array with child arrays you would need to track the [`CurrentDepth`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.currentdepth?view=net-6.0) as well as the [`TokenType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.tokentype?view=net-6.0).  `Skip()` takes care of this automatically.
- If you want to ignore a property value or array entry, you must also use `Utf8JsonReader.Skip()` to consume that value.  See *[How can I correctly skip an unknown property inside the JsonConverter<T>.Read() method of System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65402006/3744182)* for details.